# How far away does Reach let you hit?

Tags: descent

The rules for Reach read:

> The Reach keyword allows the figure to use a Melee attack to target a
>   figure up to two spaces away, rather than only adjacent spaces. The
>   target still needs to be in line of sight.

Does this mean that the reaching figure can hit one additional space away from where it could normally hit, or two spaces away from where it could normally hit? Alternatively, is "adjacent" considered to be figures that are zero spaces away, or one space away? (my question is about what "x spaces away" means, and not what adjacent means)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [this FAQ](http://www.descentinthedark.com/_r_/reach.php):

> The Reach ability allows a figure to make a melee attack targeting
>   both adjacent spaces and spaces at a range of 2

I think it's pretty clear from the way that's phrased that "adjacent spaces" means the same as "spaces at a range of 1".

Comment: This is correct.  Technically every hero by default has a reach of 1 space with melee weapons.